# Can I generate binary logs if they weren't turned on?

Tags: mysql, replication

Ok, so here's the scenario:

1. Our master went down, boom! gone (Call this one DB1)
2. We switched our backup replica server. Ok, life is good, sort of (Call this DB2)
3. Binary logs were not turned on for DB2, therefore we are missing a few hours of logs
4. We want to bring another server up and sync with DB 2

Question: Can we generate the logs for the few hour gap? Or are they gone? I have the logs for everything up to that position and after but not during.

Followups:
Data is both InnoDb and MyIsam. The binary logs have been turned on for DB2. The issue is that they were turned on 2 hours after the server was in production. So there is two hours worth of binary logs that are missing

If i'm down voted, please tell me what I can do to improve my question.

Comment: Is all your data on DB2 InnoDB ???

Comment: Where you running MySQL Replication ? Do you know how to setup MySQL Replication ?

Comment: How much data do you have in your database ? Please run `SELECT SUM(data_length+index_length) TotalSpaceForMySQL FROM information_schema.tables` and tell me the number.

Comment: Did you have `log-slave-updates` configured on DB2 ?

Comment: No, but I think that sounds like a good idea to do forward on all slaves should this happen again.

Comment: There is about 150G

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can we generate the logs for the few hour gap? Or are they gone?

They are gone. You cannot do a sync with that gap. However, it should not matter.

You need to setup replication from scratch on DB1.

During off-hours, run this on DB2

```
MYSQL_USER=root
MYSQL_PASS=rootpassword
MYSQL_CONN="-u${MYSQL_USER} -p${MYSQL_PASS}"
MYSQLDUMP_OPTIONS=""
MYSQLDUMP_OPTIONS="${MYSQLDUMP_OPTIONS} --master-data=1"
MYSQLDUMP_OPTIONS="${MYSQLDUMP_OPTIONS} --single-transaction"
MYSQLDUMP_OPTIONS="${MYSQLDUMP_OPTIONS} --routines"
MYSQLDUMP_OPTIONS="${MYSQLDUMP_OPTIONS} --triggers"
MYSQLDUMP_OPTIONS="${MYSQLDUMP_OPTIONS} --all-databases"
echo "SET SQL_LOG_BIN = 0;" > MySQLData.sql
echo "STOP SLAVE;" >> MySQLData.sql
mysql ${MYSQL_CONN} -ANe"RESET MASTER;"
mysqldump ${MYSQL_CONN} ${MYSQLDUMP_OPTIONS} >> MySQLData.sql
echo "SET SQL_LOG_BIN = 1;" >> MySQLData.sql
```

You just setup replication on DB1 and load `MySQLData.sql` into it.

BTW Make sure `log-slave-updates` is configured on `DB1` and `DB2`

Comment: Don't forget about the `--events` option.